# site-packages in Python

Tags: python, linux

When I type in the following code :

```
>>> import site
>>> site.getsitepackages()
```

the following result comes up -

```
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

What do the two different paths indicate ? On windows, there is just one folder for the site-packages. Why are they different in linux ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.getsitepackages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site packages directories are the directories to which Python installs third party extensions, and in which it looks for packages and modules whenever you import something.

On Linux, the `/usr` directory contains files that come with the system distribution, and the `/usr/local` directory contains files installed by the system administrator. So, if you install the distribution version of a third party extension, you're going to find it in the `/usr` sites-packages directory:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-twisted
...
$ find /usr -name twisted
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted
```

And if you install the third party extension yourself, you're going to find it in the `/usr/local` site-packages directory:

```
$ sudo pip install twisted
...
$ find /usr -name twisted
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted
```

Windows doesn't make this distinction, so it only has one site packages directory.